# How can I make use of this SCSS media variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, node-sass

I have this in my `scss` file:

```
$min-phone: 320px;

$retina-phone: #{"only screen and (min-width: #{$min-phone})"};
```

and have tried using it like this

```
p {
  @media $retina-phone {
    font-size: 12;
  }
}
```

But it fails while compiling the css. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code you need to retrieve the var like you did for the other one :  `#{$retina-phone}`

it turns to be then :

```
$min-phone: 320px;

$retina-phone: #{"only screen and (min-width: #{$min-phone})"};

p {
  @media #{$retina-phone} {
    font-size: 12;
  }
}
```

It will compile to

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  p {
    font-size: 12;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `@mixin`:

```
@mixin respond-below($breakpoint) {
  // If the breakpoint exists in the map.
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $breakpoint) {
    // Get the breakpoint value.
    $breakpoint-value: map-get(
      $breakpoints,
      $breakpoint
    ); // Write the media query.
    @media (max-width: ($breakpoint-value - 1)) {
      @content;
    }
    // If the breakpoint doesn't exist in the map.
  } @else {
    // Log a warning.
    @warn "Invalid breakpoint: #{$breakpoint}.";
  }
}
```